# How I can publish Next js app on google playstore with TWA

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I have created an app successfully and applied PWA.App-based on MERN Stack + Next js.
How to convert PWA To TWA? I want to show this app on the google play store.

Comment: I might be wrong, but from my understanding is that TWA is another version of WebView that gives user more complete native browser features. If that's the case, you still need to create your native app and use [something like android-browser-helper
Public](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper) to launch your web application from the native app.

Comment: @choz Trusted Web Activities (TWA) are another approach to incorporate your web application content with your Android application practicing a protocol dependent on Custom Tabs. Despite the fact that Android applications regularly include web content practicing a Chrome Custom Tab (with URL bar) or Web View, a TWA will run your application on full screen in the default browser
An application i.e. a PWA- based page can be installed on a mobile phone.  If by chance we choose to change the device, this installation can be re-made as the TWA is connected to the user’s Google account.

Answer (score 1):

Try cordova or capacitorjs.
these might be help you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).